# Use Git to create copy of directory at remote location

Tags: git, versioning

I am completely new to Git. What I am trying to do is wrap my head around some Git concepts. As a test, I want a simple thing. I will manually create a folder called TEST on my local computer at: **C:\GIT_Test** and then place a file or files in that folder.

Now I want to create a folder called **C:\GIT_OtherTest** and using Git send the contents of **C:\GIT_Test** to **C:\GIT_OtherTest**.

What commands would I need to know to do this?

Comment: If you're just getting started with git you'll probably want to read the [*Pro Git* book](http://git-scm.com/book).

Comment: I have been reading it and since I've never worked with a versioning control system I am a little newb-ish at this all still and lacking in the vocabulary to wrap my head around some of the finer points. I've been watching videos and doing codeschool tutorials tho, so I hope to be up to speed soon.

Comment: I have been reading the book (and it's awesome, kudos to the writer) but I have to 'do' something to grasp some of the concepts.

Comment: Sure, no problem. In that case: http://try.github.io/ http://pcottle.github.io/learnGitBranching/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot do this exactly as you described it. That is because Git is a **distributed** version control system. That matters in this case because in a distributed system you cannot push your changes on others -- instead they decide when to pull changes from you.

Here's how that would work (using command line git)

```
cd GIT_Test
git init .
mkdir TEST
touch TEST/foo
git add TEST/foo
git commit -m "Added testing file"

cd ../GIT_OtherTest
git init .
git remote add test ../GIT_Test
git pull test master
```

The one exception to this is *bare* repositories. Bare repositories don't have working copies of the files so you can safely push to them without overwriting anyone's work. The downside is that you can't work on files in a bare repository directly - you must clone the repository and make changes there.

For example, we could have done the second part differently up there:

```
cd ..
git init --bare GIT_Central

cd GIT_Test
git remote add central ../GIT_Central
git push central master
ls ../GIT_Central # notice how this doesn't actually contain the files we pushed

cd ..
git clone GIT_Central GIT_OtherTest
ls GIT_OtherTest # but here they are!
```

So the commands you need to know are `init`, `add`, `commit`, `remote`, `pull`, `push`, and `clone`.